# How can ı take my solana from contact adress?

Tags: solana

Hı Solana. when ı want to send my solana to my wallet I sended to wrong adress. I sended to solana contact adress. How can ı take to my solana from there. Can you help me ?

Comment: You sent it to contact address. It's bit vague. But once you send solana to another address and the transaction is finalized you can't get that back. unless the receiver agrees to return it.

Comment: What will be happen now. What ı will do for take it from contact adress?

Comment: If you know the owner ask him/her